# Read excel file in Metro app (C#/XAML)

Tags: excel, microsoft-metro, ms-office

I want to find the way to read excel file in Metro app (use C#/XAML) but probably there is no solution. Anyone know if there is any reference support to do this (like Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in Win32)? Help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it free, write your own ExcelReader, I've shared some idea here:
[Reading Excel file using C# in WinRT platform](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/4fce4765-2d05-4a2b-8d0a-6219e87f3307)

If you don't mind paying, you can try either ComponentOne or [Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com), they've got out of the box of manipulating (reading and writing) office documents.

Answer (score 0):

There's paid control available from [ComponentOne.](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SpreadWinRT/)